# Error while using CHEF "group" resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi I am using the below code to create a group, i would like chef to use "Chef::Provider::Group::Groupadd" provider, i am executing this on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4.

chef client version 11.4.0

## Chef recipie used to create the group

```
group node['was']['usr_grp'] do
   action :create
end
```

## ERROR

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'group[webspher]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
groupmod webspher returned 6, expected 0


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/WAS/recipes/default.rb

 35: group node['was']['usr_grp'] do
 36:   action :create
 37: end
 38:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/WAS/recipes/default.rb:35:in `from_file'

group("webspher") do
  action [:create]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  group_name "webspher"
  gid 901
  cookbook_name "WAS"
  recipe_name "default"
end



[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-09-25T13:36:45-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: group[webspher] (WAS::default line 35) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: groupmod webspher returned 6, expected 0
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kamararadclimber, as you also mentioned exit code 6 means group does not exist, so ideally it should create the group.

The problem I found was local to our environment. We have active directory tied up with our systems so group and users are created in Active directory and mapped to the machines.

Somehow the user I was trying to create was there in the active directory but was not mapped properly, i.e it was not present in /etc/groups.

Chef somehow was able to find out that the group existed, not sure how it was actually figuring it out in the active directory, but it was and hence giving the error.

groupadd worked fine becuase it just created the group locally and was not checking anywhere in active directory.

Thanks for all the support

Answer (score 2):

Usually the way to debug group resource is to run gthe groupadd command and observe the result.

In your situation

```
groupadd -g 901 webspher
```

it will probably explain the reason your chef run fails.

Most probably this is due to your group already exists or the gid being already taken.
You can check this with

```
grep 901 /etc/groups
```

and

```
grep webspher /etc/groups
```

Comment: Executed this command `groupadd -g 901 webspher`
There are no group with GID 901 created.

But no errors found in this, getting same error with USER resource as well.

More than that why is the "groupmod" being called. Is there a way to directly call the Groupadd provider.

Comment: man groupadd says that exit code 6 means "specified group doesn't exist"